# .mkv video playing on pc but not on mobile using HTML5 tag

Tags: html

The following code is working when I use Google Chrome on my PC, but when I try it on my mobile phone (iOS) doesn't work.

Any idea how can I get this to work?

Thank you.

```
        <video style="width: 100%; margin:0;" controls >
            <source src="static/Movies/{{movie}}#t=0" type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2" >
            <source src="static/Movies/{{movie}}#t=0" type="video/mp4; codecs=Opus Vorbis VP8" >
            <source src="static/Movies/{{movie}}#t=0" type="video/webm; " >
            <source src="static/Movies/{{movie}}#t=0" type="video/ogg;" >
        </video>
```

Comment: Maybe your iPhone does not have that codec?

Comment: HTML5 Does not support MKV files. Your best bet is converting to webp.

Comment: H.264 video in an MP4 container is the most widely supported codec. https://caniuse.com/mpeg4